# Android billing - when I test with SDK 1.6, I get syntax errors

Tags: android, android-billing

My app supports SDK 1.6 so when I added Android billing, it started giving a syntax error on this method:

```
        act.startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                                       requestCode, new Intent(),
                                       Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
                                       Integer.valueOf(0));
```

Which is in `IabHelper.java` and called inside the `launchPurchaseFlow` method

Does this mean I can not implement the new Android billing without stopping to support 1.6?  Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why 1.6? According to the latest dashboards that's 0.1% of devices...

Comment: @ile that is true, BUT 2.2 is version 8.  And there are 1-2% of devices on OS under 8.

Comment: oh yes indeed, if data can be trusted - 5.4% are on API 7 and 8, but only 0.1% on API 4 (Android 1.6) http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html Anyhow, I was curious if there is any other particular reason you want to support 1.6 (eg. some particular device you are targeting) . I assumed most developers these days completely disregard anything up to 2.3

Comment: @ile no great reason. I probably will switch to 2.3 at some point soon. But I really don't know how bad the reviews will be from the 5% of the people with OS 8 and below who won't be able to get the update.  What if they give bad reviews? lol ...my app has 70k downloads, so 5% is a lot of people who I want to keep happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [In App Billing Overview](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html):

> In-app Billing Version 3 is supported on devices running **Android 2.2** or higher that have the latest version of the Google Play store installed

Comment: thank you. So that means I either have to stop supporting 1.6 or not be able to do in-app billing?

Comment: @Genadinik - yes, it seems that way. Note that 2.2+ is 98.2% of Android devices per the [May 1 Dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).